# django-autocomplete-light ModelSelect2Multiple not rendering values

Tags: django, django-forms, django-autocomplete-light

So this is the situation:

I am using django-autocomplete-light and I got it working on a few forms, however, when tying to implement it on a M2M field it just doesn't render the values in the select field.

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    mobile = models.CharField(max_length=11, blank=True)
    customer = models.ManyToManyField("customers.Customer")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

```
class CustomerAutocomplete(autocomplete.Select2QuerySetView):
    def get_queryset(self):
        if not self.request.user.is_authenticated:
            return Customer.objects.none()

        qs = Customer.objects.all()

        if self.q:
            qs = qs.filter(name__istartswith=self.q)

        return qs
```

```
class UserProfileForm(autocomplete.FutureModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields =('__all__')

        widgets = {
            'customer': autocomplete.ModelSelect2Multiple(url='customer-autocomplete'),
        }
```

in urls.py i got"

```
url(r'^customer-autocomplete/$', CustomerAutocomplete.as_view(),name='customer-autocomplete',),
```

when i got to the autocomplete url: customer-autocomplete/  i got:

```
{"results": [{"id": "2", "text": "Oozz", "selected_text": "Oozz"}, {"id": "1", "text": "Voolia", "selected_text": "Voolia"}, {"id": "3", "text": "Feedspan", "selected_text": "Feedspan"}, {"id": "4", "text": "Layo", "selected_text": "Layo"}, {"id": "5", "text": "Babbleblab", "selected_text": "Babbleblab"}, {"id": "6", "text": "Digitube", "selected_text": "Digitube"}, {"id": "7", "text": "Feednation", "selected_text": "Feednation"}, {"id": "8", "text": "Dabjam", "selected_text": "Dabjam"}, {"id": "9", "text": "Zoomlounge", "selected_text": "Zoomlounge"}, {"id": "10", "text": "Zoomzone", "selected_text": "Zoomzone"}], "pagination": {"more": true}}
```

it renders no customers:
[image]

However if i remove the widget on my form.py:

```
   widgets = {
        'customer': autocomplete.ModelSelect2Multiple(url='customer-autocomplete'),
   }
```

It renders all customers:

[image: image description here]

I guess this issue is not related to the jQuery or JS dependent files as I got it working on another forms but in this one it just doesn't work.

What I am missing?

I should be able to get something like this:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Well, I finally found the solution. I was calling the wrong form instance on the template.

I was calling:

```
{{ form.media }}
```

When I needed to instead call:

```
{{ userprofile_form.media }}
```

This is because I am rendering various forms in the same template.

Solved!